# jquery UI tooltip - use flat string for content not working

Tags: jquery-ui, jquery-tooltip

My problem is quite simple. 

I want to use a flat sstring for the content function within the tooltip, 
instead of using the value of title attributes.

But why mine code is not working?

```
  $(function () {
      $(document).tooltip({
          content: "amsdmkam";
      });
  });
```

JSFiddle :   http://jsfiddle.net/matildayipan/vdc6adwv/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want a flat string content instead of using the value of title attribute, you also must put `title` attribute in input tag
Another error is the semicolon after `content: "amsdmkam"`.

Please check again with my edit

JSFiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/vdc6adwv/2/